# When clicking "next" on the users page, filters aren't preserved

Tags: bug, status-completed, users

When clicking on the "next" button at the bottom of the users page, to go to the next page of users, the filters aren't preserved.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Go to the users page at `http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users`
2. Set the filter to 'all' by clicking 'all' at the top.

   [image: picture of the page with the 'all' link circled freehand]

   The URL of the page is now `http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?tab=reputation&filter=all`
3. Click 'next' at the bottom of the page.

   [image: picture of the page with the 'next' link circled freehand]
4. Notice that it's no longer filtering by 'all'. The URL is mangled: `http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users?page=2&amp;tab=reputation&amp;filter=all`.

   [image: picture of the page with 'month' chosen and a freehand frowny face]

If you un-escape the ampersands in the final link, it fixes the URL. Clicking the link, however, has them escaped and thus renders the wrong page.

Comment: This is an engine-wide problem and should be posted on http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Resorath The mods can migrate if they want. I don't really use other sites so I post problems I find here.

Comment: Actually this has already been reported; http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/195306/pagination-links-borken-everywhere posting on meta stackoverflow will get you more attention.

Comment: @Resorath No. Engine Bugs can be posted on per-site metas. All per site metas are monitored by devs for bug reports. This is a perfectly cromulent post. Not everything needs to go to MSO. In fact, next to nothing *needs* to go to MSO.